# How to Add the right Crystal Reports dlls in a Visual Studio Project

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I need crystal reporting dlls for my c# application. First of all I referenced **crystaldecisions.crystalreports.engine** , **crystaldecisions.shared** , **crystaldecisions.reportsource** , **crystaldecisions.windows.forms** but this throwed a badImageException of incompatibility. I tried replacing the dlls with 32-bit files as I am using 32-bit client of Oracle so all Project Settings are set to x86. This did not work too. Now I've installed **CRRedist2005_x86.msi** it installed some assemblies in **C:\Windows\assembly\GAC** these are **CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.Report** , **CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework** , **crystaldecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore** , **crystaldecisions.Enterprise.PulginManager**,**crystaldecisions.Enterprise.Viewing.ReportSource**. Should I reference these files instead of the previous ones ?
My OS is 8 x 64. I'm using VS 2013 and Oracle 32-bit client. I've faced and resolved some of compatibility issues till now but now I am unable to figure it out. My aim is to load an xml file and show it to the reportviewer programmatically; for this purpose I'm stuffing my head with dll files. Someone please guide me what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can install SAP CRV to your PC and it will do all the work.

but if you have previously installed an older version after installation open the visual studio and add reference to your solution by selecting installation location dlls.

then check your web.config under assemblies

```
  add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0
```

it should change the version automatically if not you can change it manually.
also check your report viewer registry it should also changed automatically if not change it manually as follow:
in your aspx page at the top you will find

```
  <%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0,
```